# JavaScript image array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing my exams at school and the main question of my computer science test is to make a traffic light, that loops through different colours using arrays. I'm currently stuck on this question, and I think I'm pretty close to solving it. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myLight {
background-image:url(blank.png);
width:230px;
height:220px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myLight"></div>
<script>
var myTraffic = document.getElementById('myLight');
var myPics = ['red.jpg','orange.jpg','green.jpg'];
var totalPics = myPics.length;
var i = 0;
function loop() {
if(i > (totalPics - 1)){
    i = 0;
}
myLight.innerHTML = myPics[i];
i++;
loopTimer = setTimeout('loop()',3000);
}
loop();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this the loop seems to be working, as it loops through the different names of each image. At the top of my page for example, red.jpg will come up as words, then change to the words orange.jpg, and so on. Because of this I feel like there is some sort of problem with the way I've used images. I have my html saved in the same place with all my images. I'm only 14 and haven't been programming for long, so even though it's probably a fairly simple solution, this just hurts my brain...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use an `<img>` element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/222bq9Lt/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `<img>` tag:

```
<img id="myLight"></img>
```

and set the `src`:

```
document.getElementById("myLight").src= myPics[i];
```

Your code can be similar to this:

```
var trafficLight = document.getElementById('myLight');
var pictures = ['red.jpg','orange.jpg','green.jpg'];

var i = 0;
var l = pictures.length - 1;

(function loop() {
  if (i > l){
    i = 0;
  }
  trafficLight.src = pictures[i];
  loopTimer = setTimeout(loop, 3000);
  ++i;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function loop() {
    if(i > (totalPics - 1)){
        i = 0;
    }
    var imgUrl = myPics[i];
    myLight.innerHTML = '<img src="'+imgUrl+'" />';
    i++;
    loopTimer = setTimeout('loop()',3000);
}
```

So you will insert image into your `div#myLight`

Answer (score 0):

Change 'loop()' to loop (it's not a string, its a function) and myLight.innerHtml to myLight.src

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/222bq9Lt/

```
var myTraffic = document.getElementById('myLight');
    var myPics = ['http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FF0000.png','http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png','https://s.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/Bright_Green_429748_i0.png'];
    var i = 0;
    function loop() {
    if(i > (myPics.length - 1)){
        i = 0;
    }
    myLight.src = myPics[i];
    i++;
    loopTimer = setTimeout(loop ,3000);
    }
    loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I've managed to get a solution thanks to all of your help. I used the image tag, and also used the image url instead of using the name I saved the image as on my computer. I changed 'loop()' to loop, and also changed 'myLight.innerHTML' to 'myLight.src'.Thank you to everyone who helped!